# Flutter: Base64 convert FormatException

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to convert base64 image into Image on flutter and shows in list view like below:

```
  _fileItem(Model file) {
    return Card(
      child: ListTile(
        leading: Image.memory(
          base64Decode(file.image),
          width: 100,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

but i got this error:

```
The following FormatException was thrown building:
Invalid character (at character 77)
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAUAAAAFACAIAAABC8jL9AAAAA3NCSVQICAjb4U/gAAAgAElEQVR4
                                                                            ^
```

to testing my base64 image by [online converter site](https://base64.guru/converter/decode/image) i opened my base64 string file and this is results:

[image]

But in flutter i got error?

I converted this base64 in java native in my plugin by this method:

```
private String getBase64Image(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
    byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    return Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```

Comment: can you paste the base64 string ?

Comment: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/mpy27VKymt/ @VilsadPP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your base64 encoded string contains line breaks. may be because you copied it from text editor. remove the breaks and it should work.

you can check the string here https://www.textmagic.com/free-tools/unicode-detector  and it will display carriage returns ('\n').

Comment: Ok so how could i remove '\n' from my data? means `file.image` @Vilsad P P

Comment: I updated my question . I convert bitmap to base46 in java @Vilsad P P

Comment: image..replaceAll('\n','');

Comment: as the stack overflow link mentioned, you don't need to generate new lines if you don't use them. so modify your java program and use the flag Base64.NO_WRAP instead of Base64.DEFAULT. this would reduce the overhead

Comment: Thanks bro so much :-)